# Connect Windows mobile to Oracle Database

Tags: c#, database, oracle, windows-mobile-5.0

I have an C#.Net application that uses Oracle Database 10g, and I am currently developing a version of this on a Windows CE 5.0 (windows mobile). Is there a way to connect the Windows CE to Oracle Database directly or maybe a client(like SQLclient something like that)?

I have search all over the net, and read forums, but all they suggest is to use web service or oracle database lite-which I can't because I have to use the my existing database..

Thanks for any reply.. =)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Oracle Dataprovider for .NET http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

**EDIT:**

Maybe this will help

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/wince-tutorial-10-3-129778.pdf

Comment: Already tried that one, but it actually suggests to use oracle database lite. not a direct connection on my existing database.